# Calling open on a bytes object in binary mode still causes UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python

I am using python version 3.11.2 and opening files in binary mode still causes decoding erros.

For example,

```py
example_file=bytes([137])
file=open(example_file,mode='rb')
```

The above code will throw `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Is this somehow intended behaviour and how do I just make `open` read raw binary?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here: `file=open(example_file,mode='rb')`? Are you trying to open a file on your file system that is named by the single 137 byte?

Comment: I am simply reading into a ```bytes``` object with one byte in it, namely  ```0x87```. Its like opening a file with just one byte in it.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, why are you passing that to `open`? I suspect you want to treat an in-memory buffer like a file. You could use the `io` module for that, e.g. `io.BytesIO`. But it isn't clear at all what you are **expecting**.

Comment: `open` takes the name of a file or the file descriptor of an already-opened file; it does not take the *contents* for a file-like object. You want `file = io.BytesIO(example_file)`.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking to convert the bytes object to a buffer in memory, sorry about the confusion. So in this case its trying to cast the ```bytes``` to a ```str``` and treat it as a file name, but that fails because it has invalid bytes to convert into a character. Thanks guys, I see now.